# Disable button from option select

Tags: javascript, button, html-select, disabled-input

Hello i want to disable button when a select option is a specific attribute.

My code is this:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $("company").on('change',function(){
  if($(this).find(':value').text()=="Dove Sei?")
   $("#buttonSurvey").attr('disabled',true)
  else
  $("#buttonSurvey").attr('disabled',false)
 });
</script>
```

```html
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="company" data-size="5" title="Dove Sei?" data-width="100%">
  <option data-tokens="Dove sei?" value="Dove Sei?" id="Dove Sei?" selected>Dove sei?</option> 
  <option data-tokens="another" id="another" value="another" data-picture="another.png">another</option>
  <option data-tokens="another" id="another" value="another" data-picture="another.png">another</option>
  <option data-tokens="another" id="another" value="another" data-picture="another.png">another</option>
</select>



<ul class="list-group" style="text-align: center;">
 <li class="list-group-item" style="border-style: none;"><h4>Servizio</h4>
<div class="btn-group">
 <button id="buttonSurvey" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#voteReg" name="survey1" value="green" onclick="getVote(this.value)"  style="border: none;"><img src="Q1.png}" class="Vote"></button>
 <button id="buttonSurvey" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#voteReg" name="survey1" value="green" onclick="getVote(this.value)"  style="border: none;"><img src="Q2.png}" class="Vote"></button>
 </div></li>
```

If option value is Dove Sei? i want disable the button. I can try this code but don't run.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `$("company")` selector does not match anything, if you want to select by id, you should have used `$("#company")`.
2. Instead of `$(this).find(':value').text()`, please check: [How do I get the text value of a selected option?](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/) - Since you also set the `value` property, you could simply use `$(this).val()`
3. You have two buttons with the same id, keep in mind that the `$("#buttonSurvey")` selector in your action handler will always and only select the first one.

Comment: If i want to disable all button?

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(function() {
    $("#company").on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val()=="Dove Sei?")
      $("#buttonSurvey").attr('disabled',true)
    else
      $("#buttonSurvey").attr('disabled',false)
    });
  });
```

If you want to disable all buttons, you need use class in the selector:

```
$(".btn-default").attr('disabled',true)
```

Comment: If i want to disable all button? In this case it disable only the first one button

Comment: If you want to disable all buttons, you need use class in the selector: